# Enum.Tostring returns int instead of string

Tags: asp.net, enums

```
 [DataContract]
    public enum TargetDatabase
    {
       [EnumMember(Value = "US")]
        US = 0,
       [EnumMember(Value = "Canada")]
        Canada = 1
    }
```

**This Works!**

```
   <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Service Code" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ServiceCode"
                                    UniqueName="colServiceCode">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:HyperLink class="linkGreenBoldUnderlined" ID="lnkServiceCode" runat="server"
                                            Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServiceCode")%>' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Test.aspx?ServiceId={0}DB={1}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ServicesID"), TargetSystem) %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
```

**In code behind this does not work**

```
linkClient.NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/Test.aspx?ClientId={0}&DB={0}", client.Client.ID, TargetSystem.ToString());
```

**OR**

```
linkClient.NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/Test.aspx?ClientId={0}&DB={0}", client.Client.ID, TargetSystem);
```

when I use the code above I get

**Test.aspx?ClientId=1&DB=1**

but I want

**Test.aspx?ClientId=1&DB=Canada**

Anyone know why C# would produce a one instead of a string value ? the enum is stored on the webservice but in some places this works and some places it does not.

MSDN Documentation:

The format parameter can contain the "G" or "g", "D" or "d", "X" or "x", and "F" or "f" format strings. **If format is null or an empty string (""), the general format specifier ("G") is used.**

**EXAMPLE**

```
enum Colors {Red, Green, Blue, Yellow = 12};
Console.WriteLine("myColor.ToString(\"G\") = {0}", myColor.ToString("G"));

myColor.ToString("g") = Yellow
myColor.ToString("G") = Yellow
```

Comment: "...in some places this works and some places it does not."  Where does it work, and where does it not?  Presumably it does not work in the `ItemTemplate` you've shown in your question, but do you have an example of where it does work as you expect in an ASPX view?

Comment: @J0e3gan Good call I actually had posted one that is working and so I updated the question to include one that is not working. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of the examples where it does not work...

```
linkClient.NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/ClientAdmin.aspx?ClientId={0}&DB={0}", client.Client.ID, TargetSystem.ToString());

linkClient.NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/Test.aspx?ClientId={0}&DB={0}", client.Client.ID, TargetSystem);
```

..., change the 2nd format-item instance (the 2nd `{0}`)...to the 2nd format item (`{1}`) rather than the 1st format item (`{0}`):

```
linkClient.NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/ClientAdmin.aspx?ClientId={0}&DB={1}", client.Client.ID, TargetSystem.ToString());

linkClient.NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/Test.aspx?ClientId={0}&DB={1}", client.Client.ID, TargetSystem);
```

Comment: Ah man ... so simple .... thanks for the Second pair of eyes! I thought I was going crazy!

Comment: @MicahArmantrout: I have found that the Law of Parsimony generally rules the universe - well, at least debugging & troubleshooting it seems; and the smartest of us sometimes trip up on the simplest things...that we have been staring at too long. Once a hypothesis that something on which our code relies is unreliable takes hold, it can be blinding. Yes, a second pair of eyes is often the counterbalance to these unfortunate realities. Glad to help, and no worries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GetName Method

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(TargetDatabase), TargetSystem)
```